# Get rolling 30 day count of users logging in to site

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table of login to my site in the format below:

```
logins
+---------+--------------------------+-----------------------+
| USER_ID |     LOGIN_TIMESTAMP      |   LOGOUT_TIMESTAMP    |
+---------+--------------------------+-----------------------+
|  274385 | 01-JAN-20 02.56.12 PM    | 02-JAN-20 10.04.40 AM |
|   32498 | 01-JAN-20 05.12.14 PM    | 01-JAN-20 08.26.43 PM |
|  981231 | 01-JAN-20 04.41.04 PM    | 01-JAN-20 10.51.11 PM |
+---------+--------------------------+-----------------------+
```

I would like to calculate a **unique count of users who logged in only once in the previous 30 days**, per day to get something as below
*(note - USER_COUNT_LAST_30_DAYS counts only those users who logged in only once in the previous 30 days)*
:

```
+-----------+-------------------------+
|    DAY    | USER_COUNT_LAST_30_DAYS |
+-----------+-------------------------+
| 01-JAN-20 |                      14 |
| 02-JAN-20 |                      23 |
| 03-JAN-20 |                      29 |
+-----------+-------------------------+
```

My first thought would be  a query as below, but I recognise this would just count all users who logged in the last 30 days, rather than those who only logged in once

```
SELECT 
  CAST(LOGIN_TIMESTAMP AS DATE),
  COUNT(DISTINCT USER_ID) 
FROM 
  logins 
WHERE 
  LOGIN_TIMESTAMP > SYSDATE - 30 
GROUP BY
  CAST(LOGIN_TIMESTAMP AS DATE);
```

Would this query work in getting me a count of users who logged in only once the last 30 days with a rownum partition filter on user id? or is there something that I would have to ensure to get a rolling 30 day count?

Comment: I find the description a bit confusing. Do you want a count of distinct users per day (as in the query), or an actual *count of users who logged in only once in the previous 30 days* (as in the question)? You should probably provide *representative* sample data and *corresponding* results to what you want is unambiguous

Comment: @GMB Thanks you for your commenting. I would like the answer from my question (actual count of users who logged in only once in the previous 30 days ) . I meant to describe the query as my starting point, as I am unsure what to do from there. I was thinking of using a rownumber partition by, but don't really know how to modify it to work on a rolling basis. I have updated my original post to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

The date datatype still has a time component, even if the format mask doesn't show it. You can use the TRUNC function on either a date or a timestamp. If you really want your day to be limited to the day, you'll need to truncate the timestamp. You also need to use INTERVAL, as timestamp math and date math are not the same:

```
SELECT TRUNC(LOGIN_TIMESTAMP) LOGIN_DATE,
       COUNT(DISTINCT USER_ID) USER_COUNT
  FROM logins 
 WHERE TRUNC(LOGIN_TIMESTAMP) > TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '30' DAY)
 GROUP BY TRUNC(LOGIN_TIMESTAMP)
 ORDER BY TRUNC(LOGIN_TIMESTAMP) ASC;
```

Example:

```
alter session set nls_date_format='DD-MON-YY HH24.MI.SS';
SELECT
   SYSTIMESTAMP raw_timestamp,
   CAST(SYSTIMESTAMP AS DATE) raw_date,
   TRUNC(CAST(SYSTIMESTAMP AS DATE)) trunc_date,
   TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP) - INTERVAL '30' DAY
from dual;

RAW_TIMESTAMP                          RAW_DATE           TRUNC_DATE         TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP
-------------------------------------- ------------------ ------------------ ------------------
25-JUN-20 12.27.21.756299000 PM -04:00 25-JUN-20 12.27.21 25-JUN-20 00.00.00 26-MAY-20 00.00.00
```

For identifying users that have only logged in once, try this:

```
WITH user_logins as (
    SELECT USER_ID,
           COUNT(*) LOGIN_COUNT
      FROM logins 
     WHERE TRUNC(LOGIN_TIMESTAMP) > TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '30' DAY)
     GROUP BY USER_ID)
SELECT user_id, login_count 
  from user_logins 
 where login_count=1
 order by user_id;
```

Comment: TRUNC() works on timestamps, you don't need to cast to date.

Comment: @pmdba Thank you for your answer. Could you also please also advise on how to modify the count to only capture users who logged in once in the past 30 days?

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query, since you have string value **PM** in the date, you cannot use `cast` function, instead you have to use `to_date` and convert to date format.

```
SELECT 
  to_date(LOGIN_TIMESTAMP, 'DD-MON-YYYY hh.mi.ss PM'),
  COUNT(DISTINCT USER_ID) 
FROM 
  logins 
WHERE 
LOGIN_TIMESTAMP >= SYSDATE - 30 
GROUP BY
to_date(LOGIN_TIMESTAMP, 'DD-MON-YYYY hh.mi.ss PM');
```

Comment: AM/PM are just part of the format mask for the timestamp data type. there is no need to explicitly make it part of the cast.

Comment: AM.PM does not correspond to oracle Sql standard. `Cast` function will not allow you to convert it. select cast('01-JAN-20 02.56.12 PM' as date) from dual; -- This query will fail

Comment: I think LOGIN_TIMESTAMP is of type TIMESTAMP, not VARCHAR2, since OP does a comparison against sysdate.

Comment: @JimMacaulay Thanks for your answering. Could you please also advise on how to modify the count to only capture users who logged in once in the past 30 days?